# How to Debug Standard class in an AEM Bundle

Tags: java, debugging, aem

I'm getting the Following log noise by thousands

```
com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.CompilerProviderImpl no compiler found for txt
```

it comes up during install and startup of AEM and it looks to be paired with ClientLibrary viz

```
com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl detected [JS, CSS] library: /libs/granite/contexthub/components/modules/location/clientlib, sourced from 6 files.
```

So far, what i've found is that the following log message related to txt is from the following file

```
Bundle : com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs
ClassName: com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.CompilerProviderImpl
MethodName: findCompiler(String extension)
```

but, i'm can't debug the class as such because it is something provided by AEM and not included in the build.
How do i debug this class or atleast know from where this error is originating.(Though this question is not related to AEM per say, sharing how to debug any standard JavaSE class will suffice)

Thanks

Comment: I get these messages during startup. but they are marked as *info *, so I never paid attention. are you having issues due to this? and which aem and java version you are on?

Comment: @awadheshv AEM 6.1 and Java 8. Though they are info level, but it's a lot of log noise and i presume i might miss much any relevant info log because of this.